# Firebase rules to allow rules for collection starting from uid

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

ttm,  ptm  are the firebase uid i want to write a security rule where abc will be allowed to access all collections starting from abc_ only.

Collections :

- abc_stocks
- abc_gates
- abc_names

Need to modify this  , CuoLqcDdz0bIpVHZxPrOXHqleTm2 , rfIR2sBYwxMNyTCiYjx3cXEQJLq2

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{collectionName}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if (request.auth != null
         && (request.auth.uid == 'abc' || request.auth.uid == 'ttm' || request.auth.uid == 'ptm')
         && request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider == 'google.com')
         && collectionName.startsWith(request.auth.uid + '_');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay. So what is the question? Did your `collectionName.startsWith(...` work? Did Firestore Rules allow that syntax?